# Parsing ambiguity in a call to a temporary function object

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, most-vexing-parse, function-object

I suspect that in the code below, a call to a temporary function object with both a constructor argument and a function call operator argument is somehow ambiguous due to a most-vexing-parse issue.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fun
{
public:
        explicit Fun(int i): v_(i) {}

        void operator()(int j) const 
        { 
                std::cout << (v_ + j) << "\n"; 
        }

private:
        int v_; 
};

int main()
{
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        Fun(a)(b);   // ERROR: conflicting declaration 'Fun a'
        (Fun(a))(b); // OK: prints 3
        return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rQjVj).

Adding parentheses like `(Fun(a))(b)` fixes the problem, but I can't quite understand how `Fun(a)(b)` can be parsed as a declaration `Fun a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `Fun(a)(b);` can be parsed as `Fun a(b);` which is a declaration, and not a temporary object.

See [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: +1 and thanks. The compiler message could be a little clearer then by saying "conflicting declaration Fun a(b)"!

Comment: @rhalbersma, C++11 has extended initializer lists to make initialization unambiguous. `Fun{a}(b)` will be parsed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example to understand function declaration syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

void (foo)(int a) {
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   foo(5);
}
```

So in your case you have to use this:

```
Fun(a).operator()(b); 
(Fun(a))(b);
```